# Parsing Url Parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, web, url, akka, urldecode

I've been struggling for a while to get a neat utility function for parsing sensible parameters out of encoded URLs in Scala. Despite a lot of reading & trying with library tools I haven't anything particularly usable.

This is my current solution, using a couple of matching sets. I'd be interested in some feedback or other solutions people have for doing this.

```
def EncodedUrlToParamMap(encodedURL:String): Map[String,String] = {
  def toMap(l:List[String], acc: Map[String,String]): Map[String,String] = {
    if (l.length<2) acc
    else if (l.length==2) toMap( List.empty, acc + (l.head -> URLDecoder.decode(l.tail.head,"UTF-8")))
    else toMap( l.drop(2), acc+(l.head->l(2)))
  }

  val paramPattern: Regex = "\\?([\\s\\S]*)$".r
  val valuePattern: Regex = "[^?=&]*".r

  paramPattern.findFirstIn( encodedURL ) match {
    case Some(params) =>
      val values: List[String] = valuePattern.findAllIn( params ).toList.filter(_.nonEmpty)
      toMap(values, Map.empty)
    case None =>
      Map.empty
  }
}
```

- paramPattern transforms "https//www.domain.com/page?key1=value1&key2=value2" --> "?key1=value1&key2=value2"
- valuePattern separates each key & value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract the key/value, you can do that in a easier way but first, just type your string as an URI

```
  def EncodedUrlToParamMap2(encodedURL: URI): Map[String,String] = {
    val map = encodedURL
      .getRawQuery          //Method from URI - you get the query string directly (after the ?)
      .split("&")           //Split on "&"
      .collect {
        case s"$key=$value" => key -> value //Since scala 2.13, you can do pattern matching with extraction 
                                            // The -> creates a tuple of 2 elements
                                            // You can add URLDecoder on v here
      }
      .toMap                    // Get the whole as a Map
    map
  }

  val uri = new URI("https//www.domain.com/page?key1=value1&key2=value2")
  EncodedUrlToParamMap2(uri)
```

Comment: Amazing, that's just what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use a type which has this functionality build in, i.e. `org.http4s.Uri`. But if you need to work with a String:

```scala
def encodedUrlToParamMap(encodedURL: String): Map[String, String] =
  encodedURL.split('?').toList match {
    case _ :: params :: Nil => params.split("&").collect { case s"$key=$value" => key -> value }.toMap
    case _                  => Map.empty[String, String]
  }
```